# Create Folders from single column & single sub folder level from multiple cells on same row

Tags: excel, vba, directory

I am creating a excel dashboard and have got stuck when trying to create folders.

Basically all projects will be listed in column A and the contractors will be listed in the row next to the project. As shown below:

A[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adsMa.png)

A folder for each contractor is required.
The cells next to the project on the same row are required to be folders created at a single subfolder level.

I have tried multiple ways but the result always ends up with all contractors in each project folder or only the project folders being created. I think I am struggling with the looping of the ranges.

This is my attempt.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Create_Project_Multiple_Folder()

    Dim Rng As Range, rw As Range, c As Range
    Dim sPath1 As String, tmp As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contractor Checklist")

    Dim sub_folder_path As String
    Dim i As Integer

For i = 9 To sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        sub_folder_path = "P:\TEST" & Application.PathSeparator & sh.Range("A" & i).Value
        'sub_folder_path = sh.Range("C1").Value & Application.PathSeparator & sh.Range("A" & i).Value

    If Dir(sub_folder_path, vbDirectory) = "" Then

        MkDir (sub_folder_path)

        sh.Range("V" & i).Value = "Folder Created"
        'Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Else
        sh.Range("V" & i).Value = "Folder already available"
    End If

    Set Rng = Range("B9:E16")

    For Each rw In Rng.Columns
      '  sPath1 = sub_folder_path
        For Each c In rw.Cells
            tmp = Trim(c.Value)
            If Len(tmp) = 0 Then
                Exit For
            Else
                'sPath = sPath & Range("A1").Value & tmp & "\"
                sPath1 = sub_folder_path & "\" & tmp & "\"
                If Len(Dir(sPath1, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir sPath1
            End If
        Next c
    Next rw

Next i

End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Hope this makes sense.
Thanks
Lewis

Comment: Thanks for the edit, much more viewable. Not sure why it didn't structure the way you have done it.

Comment: An easier question may be: How do you store a value of a created folder and add a list of subfolders from cell values.

Comment: Can anyone help?